# Output single custom meta value to metabox

Tags: php, wordpress

Hopefully a very basic question.

I have a custom post type with custom meta.  I had it working ok, but after some modifications I am not seeing what i expected.... PHP is a new language for me so please forgive a dumb question.  I was using:

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);  ?>
<input type="text" id="dt_location" name="dt_location" placeholder="Dog Tag" value="<?php $meta["dt_location"][0] ?>" />
```

in the custom metabox and it was working great however now the variable is not outputting any value.  If I use var_dump I get:

```
string(6) "450000"
```

print_r also will display the value, however when I use something like:

```
echo "START]" . $meta["dt_location"][0] . "[END <BR>";
```

all I receive is

```
START][END
```

Why am I seeing data with var_dump and print_r, but not using the  method that worked earlier?

Comment: post the exact print_r line used and the exact response.

Comment: print_r($meta["dt_location"][0]);  

450000

Comment: `get_post_custom($post->ID);` it will return a multidimensional array , you can use foreach to get all the values.

Comment: Yes if I vardump $meta I get everything, including what I am after (from var)dump($meta) ... ["dt_location"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "450000" }

Answer (score 0):

The *value* attribute in your *input* is missing the `echo`:

```
<?php echo $meta["dt_location"][0]; ?>
```

Also, if you just need to get a value for a specific custom field, say *dt_location*, you can use the get_post_meta function:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dt_location', true); ?>
```